# I want to control the desktop properties (wallpaper, icons ...) from the command-line

Tags: command-line, xorg

I am using a graphical environment, but I want to control the desktop properties through scripts as well.

I would like to keep my commands limited to `bash` and `xorg` programs. However I would like it to be easily editable and wm agnostic. I am at first just focused on getting icons for minimized windows rendered on the root window. Because that is how I plan to use it.

Any one familiar with `xorg` programs like `xdotool` and `xprop`?